# Will php autoreconnect to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, connection, connection-pooling

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:".$LOCAL_DB_PORT, $LOCAL_DB_USER, $LOCAL_DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db("hr", $con);
mysql_query("set names utf8", $con);

while(true)
{
    do_stuff($con);
    sleep(50);
}
```

If connection timesout in 50 seconds,will $con still work?

Comment: you've got the code to test it, why not just run it and try if it works?

Comment: You need to look into connection pooling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the connection times out, it won't work.

To answer the question from the comment, to cope with the problem, refer to php.net manual page for [mysql_connect()](http://hr.php.net/mysql_connect) which says:

> If a second call is made to mysql_connect()  with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned.

so if you want to make sure you always have an open connection, just try to open a new one with the same arguments after the code you substituted with sleep() is done executing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: why don't you try it and see?

I believe codeburger is correct: if the MySQL connection times out, then it's gone. You could use a persistent connection with [mysql_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php). You will need to call that function after sleep each time but it will use an existing connection, saving overhead.

Comment: you don't even need to use a persistent connection. subsequent calls to mysql_connect() with the same parameters will use a previous connection within the same execution of the PHP script. so if mysql disconnects, you get a new connection. if you're not disconnected, nothing happens.

Comment: True, but my point was connecting with `mysql_pconnect` uses less overhead each time.